# refresh div only when there is new update

Tags: html, load, refresh, tweets

i want to make a button like twitter when there is new tweets
to refresh the main div like this
 how do i code it i a script like this

http://allvirtual.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/twitter-new-tweets-notification.png?w=450

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

<body>
<div id="load_tweets"> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What's the question? Did you try this? What isn't working?

Comment: my problem is i just want to refresh my div if there is a new content on my image tabel at php! than that a div slides down and says new updates! like in de image i send

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.get(url, data, success)` instead.  In the callback compare the response to the current contents of `$('#load_tweets').html()` if the new html is different from the current html replace the current with the new.